# How to search for posts given post_content AND post_excerpt using WP_Query?

Tags: wp-query

Trying to search for posts given post_content AND post_excerpt. Here is my code:

```
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'                 => 'post_type_here',
        'post_content'              => $order_id,
        'post_excerpt'              => $product_id
    ));

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($query->posts);
```

For some reason, this codes result is all of the posts in that post_type.

I need it to show the posts WHERE post_content = VALUE AND post_excerpt = VALUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I could find for this was to save my two values as post_meta, then use this code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'                 => 'POST_TYPE_HERE',
    'post_status'               => 'active',
    'update_post_term_cache'    => false, // don't retrieve post terms
    'meta_query'        => array(
    'relation'          => 'and',
        array(
            'key'       => 'META1_NAME',
            'value'     => $order_id,
            'compare'   => '=',
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'META2_NAME',
            'value'     => $product_id,
            'compare'   => '=',
        )
    )
);

$posts_array = new WP_Query($args);
```